# Forward-Chaining a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Hello a "newbie C" dev here, I'm looking for some help to translate this program written in Pascal to C:

```
type T = ^list;
 list=record
 info: integer;
 next: T;
end;
var
 L,P: T; i,ui,n: integer;

begin
write('Enter number of elements in your list: '); readln(n);
writeln;

New(L); //Creating a node
P := L; //assining P as a pointer

i:= 1;
while (i <= n) do
begin
writeln('enter a number: '); readln(ui);
P^.info:= ui;
new (P^.next); // creat a second node and automaticaly chain it to the previous one which means 
P^.next:= new created P
P:= P^.next;
i:= i + 1;
end;
P^.next:= nil;

P:= L;
writeln('your list looks like this: ');
while (P <> nil) do
begin
write(P^.info,' ');
P:= P^.next;
end;

readln;
end.
```

this a program that creates a linked list using a while loop using the forward-chaining technique, which means it creates only one node and uses it to create other nodes and chain them automatically inside the loop.
the equivalnt of this code in C is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *prev,*head,*p;
    int n,i;
    printf ("number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    head=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d",&p->data);
        p->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
            head=p;
        else
            prev->next=p;
        prev=p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is that I want to create the same code in C, but I couldn't find a solution to the "auto-chaining" I mentioned before, specifically I'm looking for a way to write the following instruction in C:

```
new(P^.next);
```

what this instruction does is basically creating another node and chains it to the previous one instead of creating a temporary node and then writing the chaining code by yourself, it's like you're saying:

```
P^.next:= new created node;
```

I could be more detailed, I want to know how to replace this code in C:

```
if(head==NULL)
  head=p;
else
  prev->next=p;

prev=p;
```

and write in a simple instruction like the on in pascal

> new(P^.next);

Comment: You're going to need to at least sketch this out in C. We can't do all the work for you.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in C that's equivalent to that.

Comment: So what's the difference in functionality between `new(P^.next);` and `P^.next:= new created node;`?

Comment: @interjay 
difference is if you don't use new (P^.next) the code looks like this:
    new (temp);
    p^.next:= temp;
    p:= temp;
you basically have to creat a temporary pointer and use it along the way.

Comment: If this is about saving a line, you can just write `p->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` in one line. If not, then I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Or you can do `p->next = malloc(sizeof(*p->next));`.

Comment: *"what this instruction does is basically creating another node and chains it to the previous one instead of creating a temporary node and then writing the chaining code by yourself,"* -- is semantics. Regardless whether you call it temporary or you simply call it a node, you must allocate one new node for each node you add to the list. Whether you do that in one-line of code or three is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that this:

```
if(head==NULL)
  head=p;
else
  prev->next=p;

prev=p;
```

is not the same as this:

```
new(P^.next);
```

but if you want an equivalent of `new(P^.next);`, you can use `malloc` to allocate memory:

```
p->next = malloc(sizeof(*p->next));
```

You should make sure to check if the pointer returned by `malloc` is `NULL`, too:

```
if(!p->next)
{
    perror("malloc()");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```